# Is there a way to have WordPress autodetect page templates in the page-templates directory and any sub-folders?

Tags: theme-development, themes, page-template

I know you can put custom page templates in the page-templates directory and WordPress will automatically detect them and make them selectable from a dropdown in the admin, but I would love to be able to further organize these in sub-directories...for example:

- page-templates

  - some-template.php (works fine)
  - another-template.php (works fine)
  - products (sub-dir)

    - product-specific-template.php (not detected by default)
    - product-specific-template2.php (not detected by default)

Is there a way to tell WordPress to automatically detect all templates within page-templates and any subdirectories within page-templates ?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I suspect you could scan those folders yourself and filter the dropdown, I'm not sure of the filter to do that though, and it might cause compatibility issues particularly with 3rd party plugins that implement their own template system but still use the same wording to describe their feature, e.g. WooCommerce specific template files

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the `theme_templates` filter (see the [`get_page_templates()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_templates/) function). What you need is a function that walks through the sub-directories and returns all the page templates. Then you hook it into that filter.

You could create a function based on `get_post_templates()`, replacing the call to `get_files()` with a function that scans subdirectories as well.

This approach is a bit unstable, maybe, because you're copying core code that itself could change. Your code would be in the theme or plugin, but if the core version of `get_post_templates()` changed, you'd want to update your version of it as well.